# Tuning Garbage collector with the help of GCViewer

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm

I'm analysing the logs from the garbage collector (using HotSpot VM) of a cluster composed by 10 nodes. I'm using parallel GC for young generation and Concurrent Mark Sweep for old.

The logs are similar in all the nodes, so the data below is from the node 1 reported by GCViewer:

**Summary**

Total time: ~14h

Throughput: 99,49%

Number of full gc pauses: 7

Number of gc pauses: 4722

GC performance: 36.958,8M/s

**Memory**

Total Heap (usage/max): 6.347,9M (79.7%) / 7.967M

Tenured Heap (usage/max): 4.457M (75%) / 5.942M

Young Heap (usage/max): 2.025M (100%) / 2.025M

Freed by full GC: 13.539,5M (0,2%)

Freed by GC: 8.367.939,6M (99,8%)

InitiatinOccFraction (avg/max): 16,1%/38,3%

Total Promotion: 12.678,919M

**Pause**

Full GC pauses: 7

Min/max full gc pause: ~0,5s / 8.2s

Total: 38,11s (14,4%)

GC pauses: 4722

Min/max full gc pause: ~0,00007s / 1.06s

Total: 226,41s (85,6%)

From this data I think the performance of the GC is just fine. Throughput always above 99,1 percent. We have a lot more low pauses than full GC which is something desirable too.

From my prespective, we have a system that does more or less one full GC each 2 hours, and the time spent with the GC in that time is ~260s (full GC pause time + low pause time). Tenured heap does not seems to be a problem, never gets too full, although young heap is always full.

The only thing that I see that can be bad is the fact that the young heap is always full, and because of this, too many low pauses are being executed. But, increasing this heap will certainly increase the time of the GC low pauses which is not desirable. 
Another issue is related to the InitiatinOccFraction value (avg: 16,1%/max:38,3%). Mark Sweep initial mark might be starting too soon? What would be the advantage of increasing the minimum threshold of this property (CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction)?
Last one, it seems to me that Full GC aren't releasing too much memory in the old generation space. Freed by full GC: 13.539,5M (0,2%). If this happens, this means that I have objects that need to live long and the only solution would be to increase the heap space for the old generation?

Do you see any obvious problems with these reports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think below are the things which are not fine,

**Number of full gc pauses: 7**

which should be ideally 0 and minimal in practice.

**Total: 226,41s (85,6%)**

GC time is very high which means GC activity is happening frequently.

**Tenured Heap (usage/max): 4.457M (75%) / 5.942M**

**Young Heap (usage/max): 2.025M (100%) / 2.025M**

I think you should try increasing your young generation size a little more.
In addition check GC policies also which will help you to improve performance and which suits your application.
Also try using GC parameters to minimize GC pauses i.e. No. of parallel GC threads etc.

Comment: That Total: 226,41s is the total time of the low pauses. 226,41s in 14h of application usage seems a lot? My issue with the increase of the young heap is that I will alse increase the time of the pauses, which is the one thing I see that must be lowered. If I minimize the number of GC pause, that won't increase the number of Full GC pauses? Do you have any ideas on how to reduce the number of full GC pauses?

Comment: Did you get any heapdump? If yes analyze it check what (which object)is eating the heap. From object you can get the code which is not efficient. Improve the code quality, remove memory leaks if any and as I have mentioned apply GC policies which will also help you.

Comment: Sry I didn't understand what you meant by this, My issue with the increase of the young heap is that I will alse increase the time of the pauses, which is the one thing I see that must be lowered

Comment: Well if I increse the young heap size, gc will take longer to process the low pauses increasing their overall time. Won't it?

Comment: Yes, but I see 100% util of young heap, If you increase it a bit then I think no. of young GC will be less eventually low pauses time should reduce. As GC tuning is not straight forward task, but you can try this change.

Comment: Ok, I'll focus on reducing the low pauses. For this I'll start with your sugestion of increasing the young heap size (without affecting the tenured heap size). Next step I was thinking of increasing the number of parallel threads uses in the collection of the young objects. To see if I can decrease the time spent in the low pauses

Comment: Yes, have a look at GC policies also.

Comment: please up vote/accept the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: What do you mean by a GC policies? I've read something about that, and for what I've understood, it just changes the "target" of the GC: to maximize throughput or to minimize pause times. For the IBM jvm, I've found the availlable policies, but for the HotSpot I didn't. Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: okay, I didn't know about your JVM so suggested about policies. for hotspot JVM, try things which we have already discussed. In hotspot JVM parallel collection modes are more and have their own pro's and cons. Read about them as well.